# Connecting to an instance of Grails inside Intellij from outside localhost

Tags: intellij-idea

Not sure if this is just a minor configuration issue or otherwise, but when I run my grails app from within IntelliJ (via either run or debug), I never seem to be able to hit it from outside my localhost. So I can't hit my server from any of the other machines on the network, or from my phones when I'm trying to do WAP development. Yet, when I do `grails run-app` from the terminal, things work fine. I imagine it has something to do with how IntelliJ is binding the server, but does anyone have ideas on how to get it working? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Intellij configuration that you use to start the server, set 'Server host' to the hostname of your machine. If it is set to 'localhost' you can't connect using the actual hostname of the machine.

Answer (score 1):

You should launch Grails with debug parameters (grailsDebug) and create a Remote debug run configuration in IntelliJ IDEA's Run Configurations combobox. Enter your host name and port there and you can connect now.

Comment: This approach still requires grails to be run via the command line though does it not? It works as a partial solution, but ideally I could run directly within IntelliJ (we run into some memory issues when running command line that I haven't been quite able to get around).